# Google search by image - Completely fails - drag and drop just loads image in browser

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, images, google-search

I am trying to use Google Search by Image, which was apparently implemented in July.
Here are [the instructions](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/searchbyimage.html)

You are supposed to be able to drag an image from your computer onto the search box at images.google.com to search by image.  When I drag and drop, the browser just loads the image (such as file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Home/Desktop/some_pic.jpg).

Also, there's a camera button on the end of the search box, and you are supposed to be able to press it to select a local file.  When I put my mouse on it, it changes to a hand, but clicking it does nothing.  I tried turning off my Firewall, and running Firefox in Safemode, in case an add-on was interfering.  JavaScript is enabled.

Firefox 5.01; Windows XP SP3

Comment: I can simulate this if I drop the image into the area other than the search box, but not if I drng & drop it into the search box. Can you try that?

Comment: Yes.  I dragged the image all over and near the text box, seeing if the icon would change, or the text box would highlight, or something.

Answer (score 1):

Google Image Search still has some compatibility issues.

Try to upload your image to an [image hoster](http://imageshack.us/) or to [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com). Then open the image in your browser and drag and drop it from one browser window to another. Fetching images from URLs seems to work better than local upload. If that doesn't work, Chrome will surely do the job for you.

As an alternative to Google Image Search, you can use [TinEye](http://www.tineye.com/).

Comment: When I drag the Van Gogh picture right on the images.google.com page, it loads the text "http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQidl6KX2jRWNeCA6jT_TjWG7NlI3aRiB_AcDsA9Y5owS2cr9G6" in the search box.  When I click the search images button, there are no relevant matches.  I suppose I could install Google Chrome...  I really want to use one browser.  

I saved the Van Gogh image from the Google Image search home page to my desktop, then uploaded it to TinEye.  There are around 3,000 relevant matches.  Thanks.  Google has a very serious Firefox compatibility issue.